# Which is faster: JSON Data or JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am curious whether or not it is faster to pass an object in JSON format from a Node.JS express server to the client with JSON.stringify() or to leave it as a JavaScript object.  It will pass either way, so I am curious which one is faster.

My first instinct is that leaving it as an object would be faster because there is no stringify or parsing involved.  However, as a JSON object, I think that it might send in a more compact format making it easier/quicker to send?

Any resources or help would be much appreciated.

Here is my server:

```
router.get('/trip/:name', function(req, res){
Comma.findById(req.params.name, function(er, doc){
    res.json(doc.toObject())
})});
```

Here is my client:

```
$.getJSON('/trip/' + tripPoint[0], function(result2){
   console.log(result2) 
})
```

Comment: Send it from where to where?

Comment: Depends what you are doing which is totally unclear. Please provide example(s)

Comment: does it make a difference the use case?  It is from an express server to a client on the browser @charlieftl

Comment: You realize Express will stringify it anyways, right?

Comment: The question was likely downvoted because it wasn't specific enough and it wasn't clear what you mean at all. You didn't posted actual code that caused the question. *My first instinct is that leaving it as an object would be faster because there is no stringify or parsing involved* - it won't become a string by magic. JSON.stringify is still called by the framework (Express) when you call `res.send`. An object cannot be transferred over HTTP without being serialized/

Comment: *When I send the object, it displays in the console as an object not a string.* - because you're watching on results of jQuery's work. You're dealing with too many tiers at once. If you're interested in what you're really receiving from web server, consider using Postman. *why should I stringify it* - you likely shouldn't, `res.json` should do this for you. It may be not a stupid question but it wasn't asked as a good one, I'd suggest to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I cannot provide you with a link because there are too many things to teach about - start with Express docs.

Comment: Thank you very much estus.  That is what I was looking for.  -just a general direction.  I will check out all those resources.

Comment: As for direction, one of efficient ways to understand how things work is to check sources. Express is quite thin and simple, sometimes that's easier than reading docs that may be lacking. Want to know what exactly res.json does? Check it yourself, https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L260 . That's steep learning curve but it pays off.

Comment: That is awesome.  It did not even cross my mind to do that.  Thanks again.